# Python Ancient numeral to numeral

Tags: python, numeral-system

```
def babylonian(symbols):

    table=[["T",1], ["<",10],["\\",0]]
    returning=0
    for pair in table:

    forTrue=True

    while forTrue:
        if len(symbols)>=len(pair[0]):

            if symbols[0:len(pair[0])]==pair[0]:
                returning+=pair[1]
                symbols=symbols[len(pair[0]):]

            else:
                forTrue=False
        else:
            forTrue=False

return returning
```

Hello, what will I have to do so I can get an output similar to this:

```py
print(babylonian(['TT', '<<']))
# should output [2,10]

print(babylonian(['<<T', 'TTT', '//', '<<<<TTT']))
# should output [21,3,0,43]
```

Currently I can only output the numerals from the tables and if I try to stack ex. `TT`, `<<` I get an output of 0.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to make it simple,this is my fist try:

```
import collections

def babylonian(symbols):
    table=[{"T":1}, {"<":10},{"\\":0}]
    socre = []
    totle = 0
    ld = [collections.Counter(each) for each in symbols]
    for d in ld:
        for k,v in d.items():
            for t in table:
                totle += t.get(k) * v if t.get(k) else 0
        socre.append(totle)
        totle = 0
    return socre
print(babylonian(["<<T", "TTT","//", "<<<<TTT"]))
```